# Trying to setup a virtual environment on my Mac

Tags: python

On my MacBook Air I am trying to setup a virtual environment using the following terminal command.

```
pyvenv-3.5 env
```

I have Python 3 installed and my version of pip is 9.0.1.  This works on my iMac but on this machine it is not working.  I get the following error.

```
zsh: command not found: pyvenv-3.5
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure pyvenv-3.5 is installed?

Comment: How can I check if it is? If it isn't how would you install it?